# Excel-VBA: Count occurrencies of a different strings and list them

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, find-occurrences

Today I have the following problem: I have 2 columns of x rows (doesn't matter how many) in Excel with a string in each one, like this

```
   A                B
 Apple            Potato
 Banana           Potato
 Apple            Potato
 Orange           Apple
```

Each string can appear in both column.

I need to obtain the following results:

```
Fruit          Occurrencies
Apple               3
Banana              1
Potato              3
Orange              1
```

Now, I know for sure that there's a way much faster than what I could think of and I'd appreciate any help you can give.
My solution would consist in storing one by one the strings in an array checking each time if they are already contained in the slots before the current one and, if not, counting its occurrencies too. For example after having stored all the strings in an array (which I will now call `Fruit()`):

```
Dim Str() As Variant
Dim Flag As Boolean

For i = LBound(Fruit)+1 to Ubound(Fruit)
    Flag = True
    For j = i to LBound(Fruit)
        If Fruit(i) = Fruit(j) Then
            Flag = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Flag = True Then
        Str(k,0) = Fruit(i)
        For y = LBound(Fruit) to UBound(Fruit)
            if Str(k,0) = Fruit(y) Then Str(k,1) = Str(k,1)+1
        Next
        k = k+1
    End If
Next
```

This is totally crazy and I **know** there's an easier solution... I just can't find it.

Comment: Might be worth having a read here: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/file/generate_a_word_frequency_list

Comment: That's great Gareth, but how do I can access the results of a Pivot Table (for example I need to store in an array the different words and occurrences)? Considering that I'm totally ignorant about Pivot Tables, can I create one without "writing it down" in my Worksheet?

Comment: Do you need a programmatical solution (VBA) or would you prefer some manual datasheet actions?

Comment: Programmatical please. As stated, I can't modify my datasheet/insert formulas and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dictionary object, it looks pretty straightforward to me

```
Sub fruitsCount()

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim sourceMem As Object
    Dim curRow as integer

    'CHANGE TO WHATEVER SHEET NAME YOUR ARE USING
    With Worksheets("SOURCE_SHEET")
        Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row)
    End with

    Set sourceMem = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

    For Each cell In sourceRange
        On Error GoTo ERREUR
        sourceMem.Add cell.Value, 1
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

    curRow = 2

    'CHANGE TO WHATEVER SHEET NAME YOUR ARE USING
    With Worksheets("DESTINATION_SHEET")
        .Range("A1").Value = "Fruit"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Occurencies"
        For Each k In sourceMem.Keys
            .Range("A" & curRow).Value = k
            .Range("B" & curRow).Value = sourceMem(k)
            curRow = curRow + 1
        Next k
    End With

    Set sourceMem = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ERREUR:

    sourceMem(cell.Value) = sourceMem(cell.Value) + 1
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Edit: the logic behind the code is actually fairly simple, and relies on the dictionary object which allows to garner (key, value) pairs. Here the keys will be the fruit names, and the values the number of occurences for each fruit. The distinctive feature of the dictionary object the code relies on is that it won't allow duplicate keys - any time you try and add a key that already exists in the dictionary, a runtime error will be issued.

So the code just scans through each and every cell of your source range and it tries to add its value as a key to the dictionary:

- if the operation succeeds, then this is the first occurence for that fruit in the source range - it is added as a key to the dictionary, and its paired value is set to 1
- else, the fruit already exists as a key in the dictionary - and thus an error occurs when trying to add the fruit to the dictionary. The code then jumps to the ERREUR error hanlder to increment the value paired with that existing fruit key in the dictionary, and resume normal execution from there

Hopes that helps clarifying

Comment: This is a bit dark to me, care to explain how this thingy works?

Comment: Sure I am going to explain as an edit in the response section in a bit, it's getting too messy in the comment

Comment: is it possible that `Set dic = Nothing` was sourcemem instead? Also, can I declare k as a string (if I understood correctly)?

Comment: I have cleaned up a bit - there also was an issue with the sheet selection at the start. Should be fine now, apologies about that. Re declaring k as a string, this is a good question - I don't think you can do this though. The variable type doesn't actually equate with a string as far as I know, even if it may seem to look like one in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Checking yours as a correct answer and +1 for help, but I wanted to share with the community the effort to make this work for an array too:

```
Private Function FilesCount(SourceRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim SourceMem As Object
    Dim Occurrencies() As Variant
    Dim OneCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set SourceMem = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

    For Each OneCell In SourceRange
        On Error GoTo Hell
        SourceMem.Add OneCell.Value, 1
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

    ReDim Occurrencies(SourceMem.Count - 1, 1)

    For i = 0 To SourceMem.Count - 1
        Occurrencies(i, 0) = SourceMem.Keys()(i)
        Occurrencies(i, 1) = SourceMem.Items()(i)
    Next i

    Set SourceMem = Nothing

    FilesCount = Occurrencies

    Exit Function

Hell:

    SourceMem(OneCell.Value) = SourceMem(OneCell.Value) + 1
    Resume Next

End Function
```

It returns an (n x 2) array, in which there are n names and their occurrence in the selected range